# show added to cart message in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

As mentioned above I want to display "product added to cart message" in woocommerce.

I know there is some kind of built in function

```
wc_add_to_cart_message()
```

If I paste it in index page together with

```
wc_print_notices();
```

Like this:

```
wc_add_to_cart_message('products');
wc_print_notices();
```

wc_add_to_cart_message('products');
wc_print_notices();

then my current output is:

```
“” has been added to your cart.
```

My desired output is that it would return that particular product name together with a message.

but what would be the proper way of using it?

Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

In that function you actually have to give product id or array of product ids, so your line should look like:

`wc_add_to_cart_message($product_id);`